# Convert simple c++ program to assembly (68000)

Tags: c++, assembly

I have an existing program written in c++ that counts the number of words.  How would I go about converting this to assembly to run on something like the 68000 processor?  Where should I start?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i=0;
    int words=0;
    bool last_space=true;
    while( test_string[i]!=0)
    {
        if(!last_space && test_string[i]==' ')//end of word - space preceded by not space must handle multi spaces
            words=words+1;
        if (test_string[i]==' ')
            last_space=true;
        else
            last_space=false;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with a 68000 compiler and look at its assembler output "-S"

Comment: I would start by running it through a compiler and looking at it...

Comment: You should start from learning assembly for 68000 processor.

Comment: About 20 years ago, I would have been able to do this after 6 pints of beer with one hand tied behind my back. Unfortunately since 1996 or so, I haven't touched 68K assembler once, so it's fallen off the cache...

Comment: @mats, exactly my thoughts. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few hints as this seems to be some typical homework assignment:

You have to loop until a certain condition is fullfilled. So you should look up your assmebly instruction book and find commands where you can read a byte from memory compare it, branch and jmp instructions.

I would start with a simple loop and when you know how to do this, add the next conditions, checking for spaces and so on.